# Tar files in order

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, tar

I am taring files using this script

```
tar -cvf test.tar -C /home/user/Desktop/filestoTar File_one zap_file
tar -rvf test.tar -C /home/user/Downloads/test Auto_file rocket_file
```

And I want to untar them, and want the directory when I untar them to contain

```
Auto_file
File_one
rocket_file
zap_file
```

in this order. How can I achieve it? Also what is the difference between my code and

```
  tar -cvf test.tar -C /home/user/Desktop/filestoTar File_one zap_file &&\
    tar -rvf test.tar -C /home/user/Downloads/test Auto_file rocket_file
```

It seems `&&\` does nothing

Comment: Why would the order matter to you? Any solution which depends on file order is prone to failures.

Comment: Making sure files are in the right order in a directory doesn't have any logical meaning in Linux.  When you list the files you can specify a sort order but the files don't have any intrinsic order in the directory.

Comment: `&&` is the logical and of command execution -- only if the first command is successful, the latter is executed. The `\\` at the end is an escape character that tells the shell to continue the command to the next line. Here `tar` is successful because you likely have the input files in place.

Answer (score 0):

`tar -r` is used to append files to the end of the archive, so you would have to change the order of tar commands to achieve what you want.

As for the 2nd part - `&&` is logical AND in bash - the next command is only executed if the first command completed without errors.

In other words - the first command would attempt to append files even if the first command failed, whereas the 2nd form would ensure the 2nd tar would not be tried unless the 1st tar succeeded.

A naive approach to your question would be something like:
`tar -cvf test.tar -C /home/user/Downloads/test Auto_file && tar -rvf test.tar -C /home/user/Desktop/filestoTar File_one && tar -rvf test.tar -C /home/user/Downloads/test rocket_file && tar -rvf test.tar -C /home/user/Desktop/filestoTar zap_file`